# MvxFileStore TryReadTextFile shows unknown member?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to use the IMvxFileStore plugin. I have it installed in both the Core and Droid project but when it comes to using the methods nothing happens. When using the TryReadTextFile(path, out myString) method it is suggesting that it is an unknown member.

I assume this is because it hasn't registered this correctly. I am trying to do this in a FileStub which is used for a test version of my application. Constructor and code below.

```
public FileStub(IMvxFileStore file, IMvxJsonConverter jsonConverter)
    {
        _file = file;
        _jsonConverter = jsonConverter;
    }

public async Task<MyObj> GetMyObj()
    {

        string myString;
        var path =  _file.PathCombine("MyApp/", _userId + ".json");
        _file.EnsureFolderExists("MyApp");

        if(_file.TryReadTextFile( path, out myString))
            return Deserialize<MyObj>(myString);
        throw new Exception("No File Exists!");
    }
```

In my App.cs class in the override for the Initialise method I am using the below code.

```
public override void Initialize()
    {
        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

#if (MyTestConfig)          

        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Stub")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
#endif

        RegisterAppStart(new MyAppStart());
    }
```

I do have another class named FileService which implements that interface. I have checked using breakpoints that it doesn't go inside this code but does go into the Stub.

I have tried a couple of methods of registering the service with no luck. Does anyone share the correct way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you have mixed versions of the assemblies - check that all your nuget references are to the same package versions.

Comment: Everything was updated to 3.1.1 last week. Looking at the File references they are all to 3.1.1.

Comment: All I can suggest is "Clean and try again" - sorry